How to report Wi-Fi network SSID display error?
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
In previous versions (e.g. 22.04) it would just display ¯\_(ツ)_/¯, without \302\257....


It looks like UTF-8 text displayed the hard way. Look at your system's $LANG setting.

@waltinator, en_US.UTF-8

Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].
